# Define string between comma x and comma y the split all bytes using a comma

Tags: python, regex

I have some data that I am parsing which takes the following format:

```
8344,5354,Binh Duong,1,0103313333333033133331,1,13333333331,1,00313330133
,8344,7633,TT Ha Noi,2,3330333113333303111303,3,33133331133,2,30333133010
....more data.....
```

The first record does not start with a comma, but all subsequent rows of data do. I want to take all the numbers between the 4th and 5th comma on the first line and 5th and 6th comma on all other lines and split this string using commas.

So in the above example '0103313333333033133331' should print as '0,1,0,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,1'. The difficulty is that the length of the string between comma x and y varies depending on what data I am parsing. I've used regex's to isolate the string in question provided it has 16 digits in it, however this is not the case in all items I might be parsing.

As a result using a .format() method with 16 instances of '{},' threw up a tuple index error on items where the string was not 16 bytes long.

Can anyone suggest a method of achieving what I want?

Thanks

Comment: It is always 22 digits on each line you need to get?

Comment: @alecxe hi alecxe, no the number can vary massively depending on what i am parsing.

Comment: ok, so, this is a comma-separated data that you can parse via `csv` module. The question is: do you know on what position would the set of digits appear? (e.g. always between the 4th and 5th commas)

Comment: @alecxe yes, it will always be between the 4th and 5th commas on the first line of data and always between the 5th and 6th on all subsequent lines

Comment: Are you really wanting to use regex for this?

Comment: @hwnd there is a long backstory as to why i need to use regex to generate the strings that I am then parsing and looking for substrings to separate with commas. the second part of the task, the splitting the substring with commas does not need to be done using regex...any method will do. thanks

Comment: @user3045351 so, do you want the longest numbers? Can you grab them like `\d{14,}`? And then split it by `\d`?

Comment: i want to split by /d but the length of the string between the commas specified will change wildly depending on records parsed, but they will always bee in the same place in the wider string.

Comment: @user3045351 my questions is... from your sample text do you want the longest number and then split them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different approach with a regex that grabs the 5th element of the comma separated line from the end:

```
>>> import re
>>> lines = ['8344,5354,Binh Duong,1,0103313333333033133331,1,13333333331,1,00313330133',',8344,7633,TT Ha Noi,2,3330333113333303111303,3,33133331133,2,30333133010']
>>> for line in lines:
...     num = re.search(r'\d+(?=(?:,[^,]+){4}$)', line).group()
...     seq = ','.join(list(num))
...     print(seq)
...
0,1,0,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,1
3,3,3,0,3,3,3,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,0,3,1,1,1,3,0,3
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `str.split()` to get the correct field, and `str.join()` to split it into single characters:

```
with open('xx.in') as input_file:
   for line in input_file:
       line = line.strip().strip(',')
       line = line.split(',')
       field = line[4]
       print ','.join(field)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^,?\d+,\d+,[\w\s]+,\d+,(\d+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/fD3hM0/1)**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [23-45] `0103313333333033133331`
MATCH 2
1.  [97-119]    `3330333113333303111303`
```

Then you can split the content of each group with `\d`

```
p = re.compile(ur'(\d)')
test_str = u"0103313333333033133331"
subst = u"\1,"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)

>> 0,1,0,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,1,
```

Comment: im struggling a bit to get this to work, but it is getting really late here. i will have a go with your solution tomorrow and let you know whether i have got it to work or not. thanks.